# Apache serving wrong Django project

Tags: django, apache

I have created two Django projects,using virtualenv, and serving these two projects with Apache2 using wsgi and two virtual hosts on Ubuntu 18.04. If I configure both virtual hosts in one .conf file, then projects work fine, but if I split one .conf file in to two files, one for each virtual host then only first host (alphabetically) works, for second host, Apache tries to look for files in the folders of first Django project.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, with Python 3.6 and Django 2.2.2 with Apache 2.4.29. This problem is shared on blogs by different people and I tried those solution but nothing seems to work for me.

Following single configuration file works fine:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName virenvtst.tst
    ServerAdmin webmaster@virenvtst.tst
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    Alias /static /home/raza/projects/virenvtest/static
    <Directory /home/raza/projects/virenvtest/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/raza/projects/virenvtest/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>    

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/home/raza/projects/virenvtest/virenvtestenv python-path=/home/raza/projects/virenvtest
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/raza/projects/virenvtest/myproject/wsgi.py

    <Location />
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName djsample.tst

    ServerAdmin webmaster@djsample.tst
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    Alias /static /home/raza/projects/djsample/static
    <Directory /home/raza/projects/djsample/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/raza/projects/djsample/mysite>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>


    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-home=/home/raza/projects/djsample/djsampleenv python-path=/home/raza/projects/djsample
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/raza/projects/djsample/mysite/wsgi.py

    <Location />
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite
    </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

When I split this code in to two separate files, then djsample.tst takes precedence and when I try to run virenvtest.tst, I get error message where Apaches is trying to find files in djsample project. I get following response, instead of default Django page:

I get following output:

DisallowedHost at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'virenvtest.tst'. You may need to add 'virenvtest.tst' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://virenvtest.tst/
Django Version: 2.2.2
Exception Type: DisallowedHost
Exception Value:
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'virenvtest.tst'. You may need to add 'virenvtest.tst' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Exception Location: /home/raza/projects/djsample/djsampleenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/http/request.py in get_host, line 111
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.7
Python Path:
['/home/raza/projects/djsample',
 '/home/raza/projects/djsample/djsampleenv/lib/python36.zip',
 '/home/raza/projects/djsample/djsampleenv/lib/python3.6',
 '/home/raza/projects/djsample/djsampleenv/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/home/raza/projects/djsample/djsampleenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 13 Jun 2019 13:59:51 +0000

Comment: Are you sure both of the files are symlinked into sites-available?

Comment: this is not an error from apache2, this is a `settings.py` error.  You need to add the correct url to your `allowed_hosts` list.  If you already have, then you should `sudo a2ensite [name of correct config file]`, `sudo a2dissite [name of incorrect config file]`, and then `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: I have added correct url in seeting.py. if I combine these two files in to one single file then everything works just fine. Also, if I disable any one of the .conf file, then the other file works fine.